# Quicksort Need help to finish this

Tags: c++, recursion, quicksort

Please help me I need to finish this The program works but it wont sort by the age it should sort the records according to the age please help.
i cant get it worked

This is what ive done so far. I cant figure out whats wrong

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct contact
{

    char lastname[30];
    char firstname[30];
    int age;
    int cnumber;
}
c[20];

void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

    /* partition */
    while (i <= j) {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j) {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

    /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
        quickSort(arr, left, j);
    if (i < right)
        quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
void addContact(int ctr)
{
    cout<<"ADD CONTACT"<<endl;
    cout<<"LAST NAME: "<<endl;
    cin>>c[ctr].lastname;
    cout<<"FIRST NAME: "<<endl;
    cin>>c[ctr].firstname;
    cout<<"AGE: "<<endl;
    cin>>c[ctr].age;
    while (c[ctr].age >= 100 || c[ctr].age <= 0)
    {
        cout<<"Input Age again: ";
        cin>>c[ctr].age;
    }
    cout<<"CONTACT NUMBER: "<<endl;
    cin>>c[ctr].cnumber;
    while (c[ctr].cnumber > 9999999 || c[ctr].cnumber < 1000000)
    {
        cout<<"Input Number Again: ";
        cin>>c[ctr].cnumber;
    }
    system("cls");
}
void display(int a)
{ cout<<"RECORDS"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"LAST NAME: ";
        cout<<c[i].lastname<<endl;
        cout<<"FIRST NAME: ";
        cout<<c[i].firstname<<endl;
        cout<<"AGE: ";
        cout<<c[i].age<<endl;
        cout<<"CONTACT NUMBER: ";
        cout<<c[i].cnumber<<endl;
    }

}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int choice, loop=0, tmp;
    while (choice!=4)
    {
        cout<<"\n";
        cout<<"CHOOSE"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Add contacts: "<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Display "<<endl;
        cin>>choice;
        switch(choice)

        { case 1:
                addContact(loop);
                loop++;
                break;
            case 2:
                system("cls");
                display(loop);
                break;
            case 3:
                quickSort(&c[loop].age,loop,0);
                display(loop);
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Invalid";
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a working quicksort that can handle `int`?

Comment: Shouldn't this: `while (c[ctr].cnumber > 9999999 || c[ctr].cnumber < 1000000)` be `while (c[ctr].cnumber > 9999999 && c[ctr].cnumber < 1000000)`?

Comment: quickSort(&c[loop].age,loop,0); - here are several mistakes
1 - you try to interpret single age as an array of ages
2 I suspect loop and 0 should be passed in a different order

Comment: @Alexander What do i have to do please help me i cant figure it out on my own what do i have to change please im a newbee

Comment: Is any of your code really working?

Comment: @BarmakShemirani
What do you mean?

Comment: Presmelito, You had errors and you were ignoring explanations, you just kept asking people to do everything for you. But it seems you have figured it out now, so never mind. By the way, you can accept the answer below if you wish, you don't need points for that.

Comment: Im sorry I'm new here i dont know how to navigate that much Im so sorry btw thank you for all your help guys its now working. Thanks :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `quickSort` looks correct, but it sorts an array of `int`. You're calling it this way:

```
quickSort(&c[loop].age,loop,0);
```

A pointer to an `int` member of some element of an array of structures is *not* a pointer to the beginning of an array of that member of all of the structures (which doesn't exist).

You have a choice; either rewrite `quickSort` to compare `contacts`, or else give `contact` a comparator and make `quickSort` a template function.

**EDIT:**

Rewriting `quickSort` to compare `contacts` is pretty straightforward:

```
void quickSort(contact arr[], int left, int right)
{
  int i = left, j = right;
  contact tmp;
  contact pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];

  /* partition */
  while (i <= j) {
    while (arr[i].age < pivot.age)
      i++;
    while (arr[j].age > pivot.age)
      j--;
    if (i <= j) {
      tmp = arr[i];
      arr[i] = arr[j];
      arr[j] = tmp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
  };

if (left < j)
  quickSort(arr, left, j);
if (i < right)
  quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

All you have to do is make sure that `contact` has an assignment operator that works correctly, so that you can do things like `arr[i] = arr[j]`...

Comment: How will i do that? i cant get it haha please bear with me. how will i rewrite my quicksort to compare contacts

Comment: His function is wrong `quickSort(&c[loop].age,loop,0)`, it should be `quickSort(array,0,loop-1);`

Comment: It says cannot convert int to contact for argument 1 to void quickSort(contact*,int,int )
i dont understand

Comment: Its working now Thank you so much I cant up vote your answer it says i need 15 reputation bu t then again thanks.